# Stored Procedure Using IF Statement then Create Virtual Table for Pick up Data

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[SFC_spViewPO_Select]
    (@trans int = NULL)
as 

begin

IF @trans = 1

DECLARE @AutoRR TABLE
(
    spPONumber nvarchar (30)
   ,spItemnmbr nvarchar (20)    
   ,spItemDesc nvarchar (65)
   ,spUofM nvarchar (20)
   ,spLocncode nvarchar (20)
   ,spUnitCost float
   ,spPurchase float
   ,spReceive float
   ,spReceiveTmp float
   ,spOrd int
   ,spCancel float
   ,spVendID nvarchar (20)
)

BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @AutoRR 
    (
        spPONumber,
        spItemnmbr,
        spItemDesc,
        spUofM,
        spLocncode,
        spUnitCost,
        spPurchase,
        spReceive,
        spReceiveTmp,
        spOrd,
        spVendID
    )
    SELECT  PONUMBER, 
            ITEMNMBR, 
            ITEMDESC, 
            UOFM, 
            LOCNCODE, 
            CASE WHEN Adjustedprice=0 then UNITCOST else AdjustedPrice end, 
            QTYORDER-QTYCANCE,
            0,
            0,
            ord,
            VendorID

    FROM    POP10110
    WHERE   (VENDORID ='KORGRO01       ') AND 
             EXISTS(Select * from pop10100 where (Ponumber = POP10110.PoNumber) AND 
            (POSTSTATUS=1) AND 
            (POSTATUS < 4) AND 
            (Revision_Number <> 1))  


    INSERT INTO @AutoRR 
    (
        spPONumber,
        spItemnmbr,
        spItemDesc,
        spUofM,
        spLocncode,
        spUnitCost,
        spPurchase,
        spReceive,
        spReceiveTmp,
        spOrd,
        spVendID
    )
    SELECT  POP10110.PONumber,
            POP10110.ITEMNMBR, 
            POP10110.ITEMDESC, 
            POP10110.UOFM, 
            POP10110.LOCNCODE,
            CASE WHEN POP10110.Adjustedprice=0 then POP10110.UNITCOST else POP10110.AdjustedPrice end,
            0,
            SUM(POP10500.QTYSHPPD),
            0,
            POP10110.Ord,
            POP10110.VendorID 

    FROM    POP10110 INNER JOIN
              POP10500 ON POP10110.PONUMBER = POP10500.PONUMBER AND POP10110.ORD = POP10500.POLNENUM
    WHERE  (POP10110.VendorID='KORGRO01       ') AND 
            EXISTS(Select * from pop10100 where (Ponumber = POP10500.PoNumber) AND 
           (POSTSTATUS=1) AND 
           (POSTATUS < 4) AND 
           (Revision_Number <> 1))  

    GROUP BY    POP10110.ITEMNMBR, 
                POP10110.ITEMDESC, 
                POP10110.UOFM, 
                POP10110.LOCNCODE, 
                POP10110.UNITCOST,
                POP10110.PONumber,
                POP10110.Ord,
                POP10110.Adjustedprice,
                POP10110.VendorID


    INSERT INTO @AutoRR 
    (
        spPONumber,
        spItemnmbr,
        spItemDesc,
        spUofM,
        spLocncode,
        spUnitCost,
        spPurchase,
        spReceive,
        spReceiveTmp,
        spOrd,
        spVendID
    )
    SELECT  ponumber,
            Itemnmbr,
            ItemDesc,
            UofM,
            Locncode,
            UnitCost,
            0,
            0,
            Quantity,
            ord,
            VendorID

    FROM    POPTEMPRECV  
    WHERE   VendorID='KORGRO01       '


    SELECT  spPONumber as ponumber,
            spItemnmbr as itemnmbr,
            spItemDesc as itemdesc,
            spUofM as uofm,
            spLocncode as locncode,
            spUnitCost as UnitCost,
            SUM(spPurchase) - (SUM(spReceive) + SUM(spReceiveTmp)) as Balance,
            spORd as ORD,
            SUM(spPurchase) AS TotalPO,
            spVendID

    FROM    @AutoRR
    WHERE   spVendID = 'KORGRO01       '
    GROUP BY    spPONumber,
                spItemnmbr,
                spItemDesc,
                spUofM,
                spLocncode,
                spUnitCost,
                spOrd,
                spVendID
    HAVING SUM(spPurchase) - (SUM(spReceive) + SUM(spReceiveTmp)) > 0

END

ELSE IF @trans = 2

DECLARE @AutoRRII TABLE
(
    spPONumber nvarchar (30)
   ,spItemnmbr nvarchar (20)    
   ,spItemDesc nvarchar (65)
   ,spUofM nvarchar (20)
   ,spLocncode nvarchar (20)
   ,spUnitCost float
   ,spPurchase float
   ,spReceive float
   ,spReceiveTmp float
   ,spOrd int
   ,spCancel float
   ,spVendID nvarchar (20)
)

BEGIN

    -- ANOTHER STORE PROCEDURE WITH DIFFERENT CREATED VIRTUAL TABLE...

END

END
```

Tried doing this method but it won't work on c# after calling the parameters on my stored procedure virtual table.. I was thinking of maybe it would look like this on my c# codes after connecting them.

SFC_spViewPO_Select(1, parameter1, parameter2, parameter3.. etc..) then another for 
SFC_spViewPO_Select(2, parameter1, parameter2, parameter3.. etc..).. the numbers that is found 1st at the parameters of the said stored procedure should indicate of the IF statement i set in the SQL Server stored procedure which then follows up the parameters for my virtual table I made inside the if statement conditions is this possible I have been trying to figure out how this thing works but never get one to function well yet.. :( help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the declare table statements either outside of the if block (before `IF`), or inside the `IF` block after the `BEGIN` statement.